# Error:(46, 0) Could not find property 'compile' on org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@1e88544b

Tags: java, android, gradle

I bought a source code and Im getting this error:

```
Error:(46, 0) Could not find property 'compile' on
org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler_Decorated@1e88544b
```

---

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pongodev.recipesapp"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 5
        versionName "3.0.3"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    // Main libraries, you always need this libraries in your project. do not remove them.

    // Important library to create material design. do not remove this.
    compile project(':materialDesign')

    // Library to create tabbar

    // Library to create ripple effect. work together with materialDesign library.

    // Library to create rounded, circle, and any shape image.

    // Library load lazy images.

    // Library to create simple list.

    // Library to create complex clickable list.

    // Library to create material dialog.

    // Library to create animation imageview.

    compile
    'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0' compile
    'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0' compile
    'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0' compile
    'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6' compile
    'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.2' compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.6.0'
    compile 'com.flaviofaria:kenburnsview:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.4.0'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you correctly copied your Gradle build script, it is f***ed up near the end.
The lines should all read `compile 'asdfasdfasdf'` and not a `compile` on a line and then `'asdfasdfasdf' compile` on the next one.

So the block

```
compile
'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0' compile
'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0' compile
'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0' compile
'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6' compile
'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.2' compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.4.0'
```

should most probably read

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.6'
compile 'com.github.traex.rippleeffect:library:1.2.2'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.4.0'
```

Comment: pls tell me how to fix i bought a code and im willing to edit some database files it and i have no experience in coding :(

Comment: I already told you. Just fix the error I told you exists and it should work

Comment: Your comment is missing content

Comment: if its not can you please edit it for me ill be really thankfull

Comment: No, `'asdfasdfasdf'` is of course a placeholder for your dependencies. Did you even read my answer? Obviously not.